# как импортировать модуль 'deterministic' в Colaboratory

Tags: python, модули, install, python-import, statsmodels

**`!pip install statsmodels`**

```
from statsmodels.tsa.deterministic import DeterministicProcess
```

выдает ошибку

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.deterministic'
>
> ---
>
> NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
> manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно **обновить** модуль `statsmodels` (обратите внимание на ключ `-U`, без него останется та же версия, которая уже стоит в Colab):

```
!pip install -U statsmodels
```

После этого перезапустить ядро:

```
Среда выполнения -> Перезапустить среду выполнения
```

После этого нормально импортируется.

Версия в Colab: statsmodels-0.10.2
Обновлённая версия: statsmodels-0.13.2